# Set onclick handler to dynamically created button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, dynamic

I need to create button dynamically and assign its `onclick` handler. Click handler could be anonymous function (I'm not sure how it is called in JS). It is allowed to `jQuery`.
I tried something like this:

```
<div>
    <button id="x">Show</button>
</div>

function magick() {
    console.log('some special magick');
}

function createButton(itsHandler) {
    var guts = '<button id="__internal" onclick="' 
        + itsHandler +    // <-- that's wrong
        '">Test</button>';
    $($.trim(guts)).appendTo('body');
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#x").bind("click", function() { 
            createButton(magick);
        });
});
```

but is doesn't work.

([Here is jsfiddled code](http://jsfiddle.net/evgeny_t/3dnmu/))

***How it can be accomplished?***
***UPD1***: It would be better if it was done inside of the `createButton` function.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery - Click event doesn't work on dynamically generated elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658752/jquery-click-event-doesnt-work-on-dynamically-generated-elements)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try to use [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on) like

```
$('body').on('click','#__internal',function(){
   console.log('test some special magick');
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#x").bind("click", function() { 
       var guts = '<button id="__internal" >Test</button>';
       $($.trim(guts)).appendTo('body');
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/j72aj/1/)

**Updated** In your code, below `two lines` can `create magic` for you like,

```
var guts = '<button id="__internal">Test</button>';
$($.trim(guts)).appendTo('body').bind('click', magick);
```

[Demo 1](http://jsfiddle.net/j72aj/2/)

Comment: How it could be done inside of one function? I mean creating button and assigning handler.

Comment: If you are using `jquery` then it is better to use `on`.

Comment: I can use `$('body').off('click', ...)` inside function to prevent multiple handler assignment, than use `on` to set handler again. I need it in one function because I have to separate it from `<script>` element.

Comment: Thank you! For anyone using $(SELECTOR).click(function(){STUFF}) and finding that it works only SOME of the time. Use this instead!

Answer (score 0):

try using **on**:

see **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ssbpL/)**

```
 $("body").on("click", "#__internal", function(){
      alert('some special magick');
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use on() for binding events on dynamically added elements. Like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#__internal', function () {
 alert('some special magick');
})
```

[WORKING FIDDLE...](http://jsfiddle.net/vBF9u/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it that way just make onclick value a function call like this:

```
var guts = '<button id="__internal" onclick="magick()">Test</button>';
```

But it won't work in jsfiddle, because jsfiddle put your js code in window load handler so the magick function would not be visible outside that handler.

And about your createButton function you should pass the function's name instead of the function itself, try this:

```
function createButton(itsHandlerName) {
    var guts = '<button id="__internal" onclick="' 
        + itsHandlerName +
        '()">Test</button>';//add () to the function's name
    $($.trim(guts)).appendTo('body');
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#x").bind("click", function() { 
            createButton("magick");//pass function name
        });
});
```

Comment: It is not appropriate way because it seems that it is not possible to attach anonymous function to handler.

Comment: Yes it won't work for anonymous functions so you should use jquery on method as others suggested for anonymous functions and for all, that would be a better practice, I just want to show that it can work in your magick case.

Comment: This will not work